# Conver SQL DateTimeOffset to MongoDB

Tags: sql-server, mongodb

I'm doing an script to convert a table from SQL Server 2012 to MongoDB collection, in the SQL Server one of the column is DateTimeOffset. What's the appropriate way of converting it to MongoDB? I'm creating a query in SQL Server with a javascript format so I can run it in mongoshell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual javascript format for storing datetimes is milliseconds since January 1, 1970.

For your datetimeoffset column, try this

```
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(s, '19700101', column1) AS bigint) * 1000 from table1
```

which will be accurate to the nearest second

If you want to strip out the timezone information, use

```
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(s, '19700101', CAST(column1 AS datetime)) AS bigint) * 1000 from table1
```

Comment: Suppose my column1 is this date "2014-09-18 15:19:41.3318907 -04:00", I'm getting overflow on the datediff function. Probably I need to format it in a different way

Comment: You are right, I have updated my answer so it actually works, though only accurate to the nearest second

Comment: Ok now it's converted, but check this, taking the millisecond number and save it into mongodb in this way "new Date(1411067981000)" gives me this ISODate("2014-09-18T19:19:41.000Z") so the -4 UTC was converted and I don't want to, I want the same date

Comment: I would recommend you store the UTC datetimes in mongodb, but if you really want to strip out the timezone information I have updated my answer with a solution that fits your requirement.

Comment: So what you said is that your previous answer was good? having this date in SQL server "2014-09-18 15:19:41.3318907 -04:00" will be converted to this ISODate("2014-09-18T19:19:41.000Z") in mongo and this is the right way?

Comment: That is my opinion, yes. Timestamps should always be stored in UTC, and converted to local time in the presentation layer. Discussion here: [Back to Basics: Daylight Savings Time bugs strike again with SetLastModified](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDaylightSavingsTimeBugsStrikeAgainWithSetLastModified.aspx)

Comment: perfectly fine I've got your point, you are right, thanks for all your answers!

Comment: but let me ask you something else :), when you have to search information for one specific date, you have to always convert that date on the fly to your local time?

Comment: Yes, you would have to always convert then. Of course, you could also duplicate the data a bit and store the date separately in one more column, if it will be queried often.